# How df.corr() method works?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, math, correlation

Example

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [2,4,6,None,10,12]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b})

print(df.corr())
```

output will be:

```
     a    b
a  1.0  1.0
b  1.0  1.0
```

And if

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [2,4,6,8,10,12]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b})

print(df.corr())
```

then output will be:

```
     a    b
a  1.0  1.0
b  1.0  1.0
```

Both are producing same **correlation coefficient**

I want to understand how `df.corr()` method works. Means how **pandas** is imputing the missing values?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas doesn't impute the missing values... rather it skips them...

**Compute pairwise correlation of columns, excluding NA/null values.**